# Match every word except if it contains a literal dot

Tags: javascript, regex

How can I match all words except if they contain a dot, like

> **I want to match everything** except.this **and similar words with dots in them**

I tried `\b(?!\w+\.\w+)\w+\b` but this didn't work.

No matter how I use `\w+`, `\\.`, etc. the regex engine still matches the part "ignore.**me**" behind the dot. Is there a simple syntax for it? Just escaping the dot doesn't seem to work.

Comment: See [`(?:\s|^)(?!(?:igno\.?reme|ignoreyou)(?!\S))\S+`](https://regex101.com/r/NmPWvc/3).

Comment: Do you really need a regex or a simple function will suffice? I guess if you can write a function then it will be fast and will cover all the edge cases

Comment: Well, that was the main stream way to do what I wanted to do.
I was sending a big file compressed in smaller ones, via a French service (dl.free.fr), with FileZilla, and instead of getting individual links in a single mail as they do, I've tried to parse the info from the log. In wich I needed to get the links in this form (http://dl.free.fr/vtS3cOunq) and ignore the one like this :(http://dl.free.fr/rm.pl?h=) and this Regex worked :
http:\/\/dl.free.fr\/[a-zA-Z0-9]*[^http:\/\/dl.free.fr^\/rm.pl]
But that made me think about other cases where I would need  to ignore "rm.pl"

Comment: Was the answer helpful to you?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest the following [pattern](https://regex101.com/r/Jzbdiq/1):

```
(?:^|\s)(?:(?!\.)[\w'])+(?=\s|$|[.?!](?:\s|$))
```

JS/Regex test:

```js
const regex = /(?:^|\s)(?:(?!\.)[\w'])+(?=\s|$|[.?!](?:\s|$))/g;
const str = `aaa  blabla fasdfdsa ignoremenot.
bbb igno.reme ad
It's fine?`;
let m;

while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
// This is necessary to avoid infinite loops with zero-width matches
if (m.index === regex.lastIndex) {
    regex.lastIndex++;
}

// The result can be accessed through the `m`-variable.
m.forEach((match, groupIndex) => {
    console.log(`Found match, group ${groupIndex}: ${match.trim()}`);
});
}
```

There is a catch: you have to trim the matches to remove unnecessary whitespaces that can show up since we cannot use lookbehind in JavaScript's regex, like this: `(?<=^|\s)(?:(?!\.)[\w'])+(?=\s|$|[.?!](?:\s|$))`